# Angular geolocation - display a certain location, not my current position

Tags: angular, geolocation, navigator

This function gets my current position and displays it (with it's coords) when the map shows up, but want I want is to input another location (let's say I want to display the map with it's coords from `Austin, Texas` at the start, not my current position).

I tried to give as argument to `getCurrentPosition` the location that I want to display, but I get the error `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PositionCallback'.` which is normal, the location I want to input is type `String`. Is there something like convert `String` to `Position`, or add a cast, or what do I have to modify to this function to obtain what I want?

This snippet is taken from here [How to Make an Autocomplete Address Fields with Angular Google Maps Api](https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/make-autocomplete-address-fields-angular-google-maps-api/).

```
private setCurrentPosition() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            this.zoom = 12;
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how this snippet works.

The `getCurrentPosition` function does not display some location, it's a native javascript API that provides the current location and allows you (as a developer) to do something with the position (with the function `(position) => {...}`).

The interesting code is:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="true" [zoom]="zoom" [fullscreenControl]="true"  [mapTypeId]="'hybrid'" >
   <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Here are the input parameters of the `agm-map` component, so in order to move to a specific location you just have to set another latitude and longitude using `this.latitude=...; this.longitude=...;` in your `AppComponent`

Comment: Yes, after some research in `lib.dom.d.ts` I understood that this function only returns the current location and that's it. But is there any function that can return coords using location name? Can you redirect me to some sources?

Comment: there is no function like this in native Javascript, you need some external library or API for that. You can look at Autocomplete from Google or Openstreetmap. You can also look for a public API in the government website of your country

Comment: Okay, this is what I wanted to know, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If this will ever help somebody, I've found this solution here [Address instead of coordinates](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/271) and it's working.